# Step-Down 400/230V to 120V without a stepdown transformer

Tags: electrical-power, power-distribution-unit

At my current data center, 400/230V is delivered to the racks. Is their any way I could step this down to 120V without a transformer? I'm trying to see if maybe there is a PDU that exists that can do this for me. The power receptacle is L22-20 and cannot be changed to L21-20.

Any tips or ideas on whats the best solution here?

Thanks

Comment: Sorry, why you need that? Every power supply I have seen in the last 10 years for even cheaper computer equipment handles 110 to 250 volts and thus can handle both voltages.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're running fans or something similar every piece of equipment going into that rack will have a switchmode power supply. If one of those power supplies doesn't accept the typical 90-260VAC it will probably be cheaper and easier to replace that individual PSU.

As to if a product exists (which will be a transformer in some part) there may be an online/dual conversion UPS that could support both voltages. I haven't come across one though. There are dedicated voltage and frequency converters you can buy, but again those are transformers.